# Apply bash parameter expansion on find's {}?

Tags: bash, find

Let's say I want to replace all spaces in filenames with underscores. Right now I would do this:

```
find . -type f -name "* *" -execdir bash -c 'mv "${1}" "${1// /_}"' -- {} \;
```

Note the somewhat bulky `bash -c` construct to "lift" `find`'s filename match (`{}`) to a bash variable I can work parameter expansion on.

Is there a way to apply bash parameter expansion (like demonstrated in the example) on `find`'s `{}` directly, without going through an explicit bash subshell (hopefully making the statement a bit shorter / clearer)?

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know; `find` always expands `{}` literally. However, you can shorten your code if you have `rename`.

But be careful, there are two common programs called `rename` around. The first one (written in C, part of util-linux) would be used like this:

```
find . -type f -name '* *' -execdir rename ' ' '_' {} +
```

*Strike that, util-linux `rename` only replaces the **first** occurrence of the search string, not all of them.*

The second `rename` (written in Perl, sometimes installed as `prename`) would be used like this:

```
find . -type f -name '* *' -execdir rename 's/ /_/g' {} +
```